# MS SQL/Powershell: how to kill background process on secondary node in Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2014, high-availability

I have an environment with MS-SQL Server 2014 and always-on high availability group configured (on 2-nodes).

I'm writing a Powershell Script which removes the database from the availability group (on the primary server) and then SHOULD drop the database on the secondary Server.

That works most of the time, but not always...

I use this the following command to drop the database on the secondary Server (the db is by this time already removed from the availability group on the primary server and is in state "recovering" on the secondary server):
`$SecondaryServerConnection.Databases[$x.Name.ToString()].Drop()`

When it fails, i get the error message:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: **Exception calling "Drop" with "0" argument(s): "Drop failed for Database 
>                           'Customer_2'. "** ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Drop failed for Database 'Customer_2'. 
>                            ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or 
>                           batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Cannot drop database "Customer_2" because it is currently in use.**

When i check the DB-Server (sp_who2) while the script is running, i see that there is a process for the DB "Customer_2" with Status="background", Command="DB STARTUP" and LastWaitType="REDO_THREAD_PENDING WORK".

As soon as the script fails, the process for "Customer_2" disapears.

I tried to modify my script to kill all processes, but when I do that, I get the error message: `Only user processes can be killed.`

If it happens, it happens always on the second Database. In the availability group are several databases (3 - 5).

So, now I have several questions:

- How do I get rid of that background process within my Powershell script? Is it possible to do that??
- Why does it work with the first database and not on the second? Does my script have a process on that DB and therefore the process only disappears after the script fails??
- Or is it a timing issue, after i've dropped the database on the primary server?? I have a 6 seconds `start-sleep` after the drop..
- What are these processes anyway? They are there for all the databases on the secondary server.

I haven't found a reason why it works on some databases and does not on some others.. It might be an issue with the size of the database.. Some are just a few hundred MB, while others are up to 40Gb...

I cant set the database offline or set it to single user mode, because the database is not online on the secondary server. The database is in state "Restoring".

UPDATE:
Something I forgot to mention is that the SPID of the process is normally above 50 . From what I was reading, SPID below 50 are always system processes. Is that correct?

Comment: After SQL Server 2000 the `SPID below 50 = system` no longer applies.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Shawn Melton for the clarification on that one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue (but not what the source of that problem was).

I ended up writing a Powershell function that tries with 3 different methods to drop the database

```
Function Remove-SqlDatabase
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[string]$Server,
[string]$Database
)

try
{
    $smo = New-SMOconnection -server $Server
    $smo.KillDatabase($Database)
    $smo.Refresh()
    #Write-Host "Successfully dropped $Database on $($smo.name)"
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        $smo.Databases[$Database].Drop()
        #Write-Host "Successfully dropped $Database on $($smo.name)"
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            $null = $smo.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("DROP DATABASE $Database")
            #Write-Host "Successfully dropped $Database on $($smo.name)"
        }
        catch 
        { 
            Write-Error "Could not drop database $Database!"
            Write-Error $_
            throw $_
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script, which will kill any and all active processes in a specified database:

```sql
DECLARE @sql varchar(50); 
DECLARE @dbname sysname;
DECLARE @killStmts TABLE (stmt varchar(30));

SET @dbname = 'yourDatabase'; -- Set this to your database name

INSERT INTO @killStmts 
    SELECT 'KILL ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), [spid])
     FROM master..sysprocesses pr
          INNER JOIN master..sysdatabases db ON pr.[dbid] = db.[dbid]
    WHERE db.name = @dbname

DECLARE @killCtr int;

SELECT @killCtr = COUNT(1) FROM @killStmts;

WHILE (@killCtr > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @sql = stmt FROM @killStmts ORDER BY stmt;
    EXEC (@sql);
    DELETE @killStmts WHERE stmt = @sql;
    SELECT @killCtr = @killCtr - 1;
END
```

You can adapt this into a stored procedure (install it into the master database so you can call it for any other user database you like) which can be invoked by PowerShell, or you can try to adapt this script to PowerShell itself.

Comment: Thanks @pmbAusting, but I tried a simillar aproach already in my Powershell script before and it did not work. But just to be sure, I tried your Script and got the following error message: 
`Msg 6107, Level 14, State 1, Line 55
Only user processes can be killed.
`


I personally think, this is a Powershell issue. Maybe refreshing my connection, or close and reopen it, will help... I'm going to try that

Comment: There's an obvious flaw in this approach, which is thinking that killing all processes prevents new ones from being created... even as you're killing them. As soon as this is finished, another process can pop up.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert . Your answer is proabably true for many situations, but in my case, there is no "user process" on the database, as the database is in "recovery" state. Because of that, I can't take the database offline and can't set the database to single user mode..  
While typing this answer, I wonder if I tried to take the database offline before dropping... Going to try it now. Thanks!

Comment: I can't take the database offline, when it is in State "Restoring". If I try that, I get the error message: `Exception calling "SetOffline" with "0" argument(s): "Set offline failed for Database 'Customer_2'. " --->  Set offline failed for Database 'Customer_2'.  --->ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state.`